# Decryption Issue (Python)

Tags: python, encryption, routes, tor

I'm attempting to create an onion router in python where each message will be encrypted three times before being sent to 3 nodes for decryption.

In the test I've set up below I encrypt my message three times but after decryption I just end up with garbage. I think this might be something to do with the order in which I apply padding or the encoding/decoding to bytes.

```
 simpleMessage = "Hello!!!!!"
    CMD1 = "MSG"
    CMD2 = "FWD"
    CMD3 = "FWD"

    messagePackage = (CMD1, simpleMessage)
    messagePackage = str(messagePackage).encode('utf-8')
    messagePackage = self.padder(messagePackage)
    onionLayer1 = encryption.symmetricEncryption(key1[0], key1[1], messagePackage)

    messagePackage2 = (CMD2, onionLayer1)
    messagePackage2 = str(messagePackage2).encode('utf-8')
    messagePackage2 = self.padder(messagePackage2)

    onionLayer2 = encryption.symmetricEncryption(key2[0], key2[1], messagePackage2)

    messagePackage3 = (CMD3, onionLayer2)
    messagePackage3 = str(messagePackage3).encode('utf-8')
    messagePackage3 = self.padder(messagePackage3)

    onionLayer3 = encryption.symmetricEncryption(key3[0], key3[1], messagePackage3)

    onionLayerPeeled3 = encryption.symmetricDecrypt(key3[0], key3[1], onionLayer3)
    onionLayerPeeled2 = encryption.symmetricDecrypt(key2[0], key2[1], onionLayerPeeled3)
    onionLayerPeeled1 = encryption.symmetricDecrypt(key1[0], key1[1], onionLayerPeeled2)
```

[image: The debugger shows the state of the message after each decryption]

I believe the issue is that I encode each onion layer into a byte array, and will need to decode back into a utf-8 string to read the information after each decryption.

However implementing the following line of code between decryptions

onionLayerPeeled3 = onionLayerPeeled3.decode('utf-8')

Results in the following error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte

Any help/advice is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried checking it at each step? What step fails to provide the right output? You are using several functions you've not included, including some kind of encryption package, so no one can run your code.

Comment: In the image you should be able to see the values of the 3 stages of decryption. It's meant to act as an onion router so at each stage I'd expect (CMD = "FWD", MSG="Some encryption" however this only works for the first message and the rest are garbage

Comment: Get it working with one level, then two, then three. If your setup with one is solid, two and three should be a breeze.